# How to show a ProgressBar for 5 sec OnButtonClick, then show a TextView?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have a ProgressBar, an EditText, Button and a TextView on my app layout. I set the Progressbar and TextView INVISIBLE by default.
[My Layout is like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1BGvG.jpg)
Now I need to show the ProgressBar for 5 sec upon clicking the button, and then show the TextView.
How to write java code for that?

I need to show the ProgressBar for 5 sec upon clicking the button, and then show the TextView.

Answer (score 3):

on ButtonClick .

```
    ProgressDialog progress = new ProgressDialog(this);

    progress.setMessage("Your message");
    progress.show();
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
       @Override
       public void run() {
          progress.dismiss();
       }
   },1000*5);
```

Comment: Sorry but the question asks for a `ProgressBar` not a `PrograssDialog`!

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `Handler` like this:

```
final ProgressBar progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
final TextView tv = findViewById(R.id.textView);

button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable(){
                    @Override 
                    public void run() {
                        tv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }
                }, 0);
        }, 5000); //5000 milliseconds = 5 sec
    });
}
```

Comment: this can b further enhanced calling v.postDelayder, rather than creating your own handler